# Multiple columns and rows in table Xcode Swift

Tags: swift

I need to create a table with multiple columns and rows for my next iOS app. There are a fixed number of columns and rows and each cell needs to just have one UITextField in it. I was just wondering if would be a good idea to use two for loops to create this.
Something like this:

```
    let columns = 7
    let rows = 12
    var firstRow = true
    for col in 1 ... columns {
        for row in 1 ... rows {

            let w = Double(contentWidth / columns)
            let h =  Double(contentHeight / rows)
            let x = Double(col - 1) * w
            let y = Double(row - 1) * h

            let cell = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h))
            cell.tag = ("\(col)\(row)" as NSString).integerValue
            cell.backgroundColor = cellColour(cell.text)
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            cell.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15)
            cell.textAlignment = .center
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.delegate = self
            contentView.addSubview(cell)
        }
    }
```

Anyone ever tried it like this before?

Comment: Why not use `UICollectionView`?

Comment: You can take a `UIStackView` on each `UITableViewCell` and make it `EquallyFilled` after adding 7 `UITextField`s, 1 in each stack

Comment: Your best option is `UICollectionView` to accomplish that.